# Computer Vision API Hand Writing

Tags: computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I am 99% sure it is not possible, but is there a way to have the response note if the text it read was "hand written"?

I have dug around the Microsoft documentation and do not see anything.

Thanks in advance!
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the [Read 3.2 preview API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-recognizing-text#read-32-preview-adds-text-line-style-latin-languages-only) outputs an appearance object classifying whether each text line is print or handwriting style, along with a confidence score. This feature is supported only for Latin languages.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I also tested it and it works with English also!